# Isolating a characterin a long string php

Tags: php, string

I have a string $str that I would like to search for a character and isolate it from the other strings then store it/them in one $variable, the character is a full colon ":"

Say I have string

1.

```
$str = 'water'

$variable ='';
```

2.

```
$str = 'water : air'

$variable =':';
```

3.

```
$str = 'water : air : land'

$variable ='::'
```

e.t.c...

if I  use `substr_count($str, ":");` I can count the occurrence but I want to return the character itself depending on how many times it occurs instead of the number

Comment: also, `preg_replace('/[^:]/', '', $str)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, using `substr_count` use it to repeat how many times it occurred.

```
$needle = ':';
$str = 'water : air : land';
$variable = str_repeat($needle, substr_count($str, $needle));
echo $variable; // ::
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right way; you can combine [`substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) with [`str_repeat()`](https://www.php.net/str_repeat):

```
str_repeat(':', substr_count($str, ':'));
```

Or if you have to use this multiple times, you can make a function out of it:

```
function repeat_needle($needle, $haystack) {
    return str_repeat($needle, substr_count($haystack, $needle));
}
```

Here's a [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zzcp-q8f1) to see it in action.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way ... use preg_replace as below which means replace everything with null/blank except colon ":"

preg_replace("/[^:]/",'',$a);

```
$cat a.php
<?php
  $a="water : air : land : Fire : Sky";
  $b=preg_replace("/[^:]/",'',$a);
  print $b."\n" ;
?>

$php a.php
::::
```